# net::ERR_FAILED to all external request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ssl-certificate

My website switch from http to https and after that all request to external server get status "(failed)net::ERR_FAILED" when browse using google chrome and request header show "Provisional headers are shown". Cors has been set in header with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. When I use self signed certificate, external link load normal.

Has anyone get this error before? Please help me.

Here is my script:

```
<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="picnic/jquery.modal.min.css" /> 
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script src="mes.js"></script>
```

[image]

[image: request get net_err]